# How to use SQLCipher in .Net

Tags: c#, encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

I want to use C# (winform) to read an SQLCipher database and find an open source project [SQLitePCL](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw), but I have not found examples of this use, and the documentation is not a lot. Have any friends used this thing, can you provide some examples to help me?

Thank you!

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89394/sqlite-net-pcl-with-sqlitepclraw-bundle-sqlcipher

Comment: here a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDotOWlmtWY&list=PLiNd7TUPozDET_shXjcaYQiXscVDGIZkU

Answer (score 5):

This will work for winforms, wpf, asp.net, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, UWP and any other .net project since this is a cross-platform library:

Install nuget by Frank A. Krueger "sqlite-net-pcl".

Use tutorial from his [github page](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

Now, once we have database and all the stuff. How to encrypt newly created database or open encrypted database?

Add nuget by Eric Sink: "SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher"

In the code, where you create SQLiteConnection specify encryption key:

```
connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, openFlags: SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
connection.Query<int>("PRAGMA key=xzy1921");
```

That's it. The rest will work as if it was not crypted.

Comment: I should use it in winform program .
Error The package "sqlite-net-pcl 1.4.118" could not be installed. You are trying to install this package into a project with the target ".NETFramework, Version=v3.5", but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with the framework. For more information, please contact the package author. 0

Comment: Don't use .net 3.5. Update you winforms app to use .NET 4.7

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/20/upgrading-projects-to-net-4-6/

Comment: Add nuget by Eric Sink: "SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher"   。 
What special operations are needed after that?  SQLite.SQLiteException:“file is not a database”

Comment: @诺倾情 It means that you are trying to open database with password even though it's not encrypted. Or you open encrypted database without password or with incorrect one.

Comment: but i can use sqlcipher.exe open this EnMsg.db whith mypassword. Thank you for helping me so much, let me try other methods.

Comment: @诺倾情 I tested proposed solution on my app. Not quite sure how come that it does not work for your db.

Comment: @诺倾情 I had the same problem trying to read databases created by the Android Room SQLCipher extension and using the sqlite-net-sqlcipher NuGet package worked for me: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-sqlcipher