# Problems trying to encrypt SQLite database on UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption, uwp

I am having issues trying to encrypt a SQLite database. I have tried numerous things so far but none seem to work.

- Initially I have used the (unsupported) `SQLiteConnection.SetPassword()` method provided by `System.Data.SQLite`, however since a while this method has been removed from the `System.Data.SQLite` package. Trying to take an older SQLite version turned out to be difficult since UWP is UAP and not .NET Framework.
- Therefore I have moved to `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` and used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli) documentation for installing the `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher` package and calling either `SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()` or `SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provided_e_sqlcipher())`. Then executing the query `PRAGMA KEY = 'password'` does not encrypt the database file.
- I have also seen posts where people used `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher` rather than `...e_sqlcipher` however in that case the `...V2.Init()` did not work.
- I have also looked into using `sqlite-net-sqlcipher` however executing `SQLiteConnection.Query<int>("PRAGMA key = 'password'");` does also not encrypt the database. When trying to query to the database using `key: "password"` will then result in `The file is no database` error denoting the lack of password on the database.

How can I encrypt a SQLite database for UWP, preferably using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` but other options are fine as well.
I am also primarily looking for a free way to achieve this, since $900 is quite over-budget for the project I am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I did not test with every package I listed, I found an answer to my question:

First I followed the instruction from the answer posted on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215911/how-to-use-sqlcipher-in-net) question. Then instead of trying to `PRAGMA key = 'password'` an existing database, instead I created a new database with `key = 'password'` specified in the `SQLiteConnectionString` constructor.

This created a new, already encrypted, database for me.

EDIT: I have now also tested this with `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` and `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher` and it turns out that also there creating a new database in combination with specifying `Password = 'password'` in for example the [`SqliteConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnectionstringbuilder?view=msdata-sqlite-5.0.0) will create a new database which is encrypted.

> I have posted an example project with code [here](https://github.com/Leander-van-Boven/UWP-Encrypted-SQLite)

Comment: @CarloMendoza https://github.com/Leander-van-Boven/UWP-Encrypted-SQLite I hope this helps, please let me know if anything isn't clear.